# A question about integrability: if $a,b\geq 0$ and $a<+\infty$, $b<+\infty$, then $a-b<+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, infinity

Let be $f\in C^0(\mathbb{R})$, such that $f\geq 0$.

I suppose that  $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t) dt<+\infty$.

Under these hypothesis, can I say that

$\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(t)\; dt-\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(t)\;dt<+\infty$  ?

I think yes, since $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t) dt<+\infty$ iff $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)dt<+\infty$ e $\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(t)dt<+\infty$.

The viceversa is not true, right?

> So my question is: If $a,b\geq 0$ and $a<+\infty$, $b<+\infty$, then $a-b<+\infty$?

Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: $a<+\infty$ and $-b\leq0$ should imply $a-b<0+\infty=+\infty$ (in the [extended reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line)

Comment: Umm...if you have two finite numbers, their difference is finite